# Multipartfile to File, file not found java jetty

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jetty

Here is my code :

```
File to = File.createTempFile("temp",from.getOriginalFilename());
logger.error("path: " + to.getCanonicalPath());
from.transferTo(to);
```

and I got error

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/jetty-localhost-8080-exploded-song-_-any-2047666791600130782.dir/tmp/temp8589196747448957001Screenshot.from.2017-07-15 20-29-39.png (No such file or directory)
```

On my logger say :

```
path: /tmp/temp8589196747448957001Screenshot.from.2017-07-15 20-29-39.png
```

Answer (score 0):

`Part.transferTo(String)` is a relative path to the `MultipartConfig.location`.

So that means `/tmp/temp85...png` was tacked onto the end of your location, which was probably the default working directory for your webapp (looks like you didn't specify a location, so the default location was chosen for you).

Comment: I don't why, but when I run with Tomcat server, it's working find

Comment: Tomcat intentionally doesn't follow the Servlet spec with regards to `Part.transferTo(String)`.  They wanted their implementation to behave like `commons-fileupload`.  Its only been recently that they have managed to convince the Servlet spec experts group that their version is a good idea, and it will show up in in all servlet containers this way starting in Servlet 4.0.